# RabbitMQ versionning the rabbitmq.config

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

Good day !

I have a RabbitMQ container running in a Kubernetes platform.
I push it's config via a configMap.

Since, there is sometimes a need to change the config, I would like RabbitMQ to reload it automaticly. Is there any mechanism in Rabbit to check the version of the file in a value somewhere and when it see a +1 or else to reload the changes ?

Answer (score 1):

OK. It seem to be easier to keep the config in the configMap at first, but if changes need to be done, both update the configMap and along with that, use the API to update live.

It is that simple.

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For the one wondering if the rabbitmq.config (not the ''loaded_configuration'') file can be updated on the fly in a container just by pushing a new configMap content, I do not know for sure as I did not tested it.

What I can tell, is on top of user/pass,queues definitions, etc.... If you update your TLS cert, Erlang will reload it in the seconds or a minut just after the cert file update.

Do not reload tls via rabbitmqctl as this caused the management-config to not be accessible anymore as long with the API. It might also drop connections from senders or listeners. At least with RabbitMQ 3.17.x